# Нужно сделать адаптивный блок с текстом на экран 300px?

Tags: html, css3

Пытаюсь сделать блок с текстом адаптивным для мобильных девайсов с разрешением в `300px`.

Но не получается адаптировать текст.

**Код:**

```css
.wrap_bg {
 width: 100%;
 height: 1500px;
 margin-top: 250px;
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
}

.wrap {
 width: 100%;
 height: 500px;
 background-image: url("../images/bg_1.jpg");
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size:cover;
}

.wrap div:nth-child(1) {
 position: absolute;
 width: 570px;
 height: 106px;
 left: 100px;
 top: 1901px;
 font-family: 'pt _serif';
 font-style: normal;
 font-weight: normal;
 line-height: normal;
 font-size: 40px;
 color: #FFFFFF;
}

.wrap div:nth-child(2) {
 position: absolute;
 width: 575px;
 height: 142px;
 left: 101px;
 top: 2033px;
 font-family: 'pt-sans';
 font-style: normal;
 font-weight: normal;
 line-height: 31px;
 font-size: 16px;
 letter-spacing: 0.01em;
 color: #FFFFFF;
}

@media screen (max-width: 700px) {
    .wrap {
        width: 100%;
        margin-left: 0;
    }
    .wrap div:nth-child(1) {
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
    }
    .wrap div:nth-child(2) {
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap_bg">
  <div class="wrap">
    <div>Мы вкладываем душу в совершенствование вкуса</div>
    <div>Мы относимся к своему бренду как к носителю наших уникальных преимуществ и всегда преподносим его "с поля к столу". Мы используем наши уникальные знания и опыт для выращивания и отбора для наших продуктов  самых лучших урожаев с плодородных южно-украинских полей.</div>
  </div>
  <div class="wrap_2">d</div>
  <div class="wrap_3">d</div>
</div>
```

Comment: в чем суть вопроса?

Comment: не получается адаптивность на экране 300px

Comment: опиши проблему нормально.. что куда не адаптируется. какие блоки, какие свойсва .заминусуют вопрос по самые гланды с таким содержанием

Comment: блок с текстом, эго ширина

Comment: так не работает

Answer (score 2):

Используйте  медиазапросы `@media screen and (max-width: XXXpx)` (в вашей записи забыли `and`) или `@media screen and (min-width: XXXpx)`:

```css
.wrap_bg {
 width: 100%;
 height: 1500px;
 margin-top: 250px;
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
}

.wrap {
 width: 100%;
 height: 500px;
 background: #777;
}

.wrap div:nth-child(1) {
 position: absolute;
 width: 570px;
 height: 106px;
 left: 100px;
 top: 1901px;
 font-family: 'pt _serif';
 font-style: normal;
 font-weight: normal;
 line-height: normal;
 font-size: 40px;
 color: #FFFFFF;
}

.wrap div:nth-child(2) {
 position: absolute;
 width: 575px;
 height: 142px;
 left: 101px;
 top: 2033px;
 font-family: 'pt-sans';
 font-style: normal;
 font-weight: normal;
 line-height: 31px;
 font-size: 16px;
 letter-spacing: 0.01em;
 color: #FFFFFF;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
    .wrap {
        width: 100%;
        margin-left: 0;
    }
  
    .wrap div:nth-child(1),
    .wrap div:nth-child(2){
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
        position: static;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap_bg">
  
  <div class="wrap">
    <div>Мы вкладываем душу в совершенствование вкуса</div>
    <div>Мы относимся к своему бренду как к носителю наших уникальных преимуществ и всегда преподносим его "с поля к столу". Мы используем наши уникальные знания и опыт для выращивания и отбора для наших продуктов  самых лучших урожаев с плодородных южно-украинских полей.</div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="wrap_2">d</div>
  <div class="wrap_3">d</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.wrap_bg {
 width: 100%;
 height: 1500px;
 margin-top: 250px;
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
 flex-direction: column;
}

.wrap {
 width: 100%;
 height: 500px;
 background-image: url("../images/bg_1.jpg");
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size:cover;
}

.wrap div:nth-child(1) {
 position: absolute;
 width: 570px;
 height: 106px;
 left: 100px;
 top: 1901px;
 font-family: 'pt_serif';
 font-style: normal;
 font-weight: normal;
 line-height: normal;
 font-size: 40px;
 color: #FFFFFF;
}

.wrap div:nth-child(2) {
 position: absolute;
 width: 575px;
 height: 142px;
 left: 101px;
 top: 2033px;
 font-family: 'pt-sans';
 font-style: normal;
 font-weight: normal;
 line-height: 31px;
 font-size: 16px;
 letter-spacing: 0.01em;
 color: #FFFFFF;
}

@media screen (min-width: 700px) {
    .wrap {
     width: 100%;
        margin-left: 0;
    }
    .wrap div:nth-child(1) {
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
    }
    .wrap div:nth-child(2) {
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
    }
}
```

```html
 <div class="wrap_bg">
  <div class="wrap">
   <div>Мы вкладываем душу в совершенствование вкуса</div>
   <div>Мы относимся к своему бренду как к носителю наших уникальных преимуществ и всегда преподносим его "с поля к столу". Мы используем наши уникальные знания и опыт для выращивания и отбора для наших продуктов  самых лучших урожаев с плодородных южно-украинских полей.</div>
  </div>
  <div class="wrap_2">d</div>
  <div class="wrap_3">d</div>
 </div>
```